# Surface integral of vorticity

Tags: stokes-theorem

I am studying how to determine the aerodynamic force on solid bodies in a fluid. This is using the Vortex Particle Method.

In order to determine aerodynamic forces on solid bodies embedded in a fluid,
the pressure distribution is needed. Considering the no-slip boundary condition, the Navier-Stokes equations in a stationary frame of reference
reduce to
$\nabla p = \mu \nabla^2u$,
where $\mu = ν\rho$ is the laminar viscosity. Replacing the velocity by the vorticity: $\omega = \nabla \times u$, gives

$$\nabla p = -\mu \nabla \times \omega.\tag{4.51}$$

To obtain the pressure, this expression can be integrated along the surface as
$$\nabla p \cdot t_0 = −\mu \nabla\omega\cdot n_0\tag{4.52}$$

where $t_0$ is the surface unit tangential vector.

I cannot understand the transition from equation 4.51 to 4.52. How come the $\nabla\times\omega$ magically changes to $\nabla\omega\cdot n_0$?

I would sincerely appreciate any help.

Comment: There are typos here. Your $t_0$ should be $n_0$, which should be the unit normal to the surface. And the right-hand side should be $-\mu (\nabla\times\omega)\cdot n_0$. I think. There are just too many different variables flying around here.

Comment: @ ted thanks for your comment. I also think so but this step moving from
∇p=−μ∇×ω. to ∇p⋅t0=−μ∇ω⋅n0 I copied it from a book as part of derivation and this is what I am suspicious about. To me it doesn’t make sense does it make sense to you ?

Comment: No, $t_0$ makes absolutely no sense when you're on a surface. Now, perhaps they're trying to apply Stokes's Theorem, saying that if you compute the flux $\nabla\times\vec F$ across a surface, then you compute the line integral of $\vec F\cdot \vec T$ along the boundary curve of that surface.